# How to leave a review for Office add-in in Appsource

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-js, appsource

I cannot figure out how to leave a review or rate an app in the Microsoft Appsource store.

I am logged in and own the app.  I can go to the product page and view other reviews but cannot seem to leave one myself.

Store: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps

Looks like some other people have had this issue

Apparently there is an email that follows the purchase of an app, but I never got one.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/c025f16c-40ab-413d-a61d-a6d34db425b6/how-can-we-leave-a-review-for-an-office-addin?forum=officestore

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: is this an add-in for outlook, word, excel?  thanks

Comment: I've looked at both excel and outlook ones and couldn't figure it out for either.  I specifically want to leave one for excel though.

Comment: You should receive the email approx. 1 week after acquiring the app/add-in. Has it been a week?

Comment: I think you only get the email if you install the Add-In with the "GET IT NOW" button in AppSource, but not when you install it directly in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like currently you cannot do this in the appsource site itself.  You can rate the app by going into the office add-in manager within Excel, selecting the options for the app and can find a review button there.

Within Excel go to:

Insert tab -> My Add-in dropdown -> See All... -> select the options button of the add-in -> Rate and Review